# One delegate, Two UIViewCotrollers okay?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

As the title implies, I'm asking if it would be okay to link a single delegate to two different UIViewControllers in my project. I'm trying to link  to two different VCs in my project but it's making the first VC's act weird so I'm wondering if I'm doing it wrong? 
Sorry if this is a noob question, still new to this.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details than "act weird".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this at all.

A delegate protocol is just a protocol. An object can conform to multiple protocols at the same time (e.g. `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource`).

You might have two view controllers like `MyPersonViewController` and `MyAnimalViewController` and they will have delegate protocols like `MyPersonViewControllerDelegate` and `MyAnimalViewControllerDelegate`.

You can then just do...

```
self.personViewController.delegate = self;
self.animalViewController.delegate = self;
```

The only thing to make sure of is that when you get the call backs from each VC that you don't confuse them. The best way to do this is to use the same pattern as `UITableViewDatasource` and prefix the methods like...

```
- (void)personViewController:(MyPersonViewController *)controller gotSomeResults:(NSArray *)results
```

Or something. Anyway, then you have a completely different set of delegate methods for each controller.